# Can strnlen be implemented with memchr?

Tags: c, string, posix

Is the implementation of `strnlen` that follows invalid?

```c
size_t strnlen(const char *str, size_t maxlen)
{
    char *nul = memchr(str, '\0', maxlen);
    return nul ? (size_t)(nul - str) : maxlen;
}
```

I assume that `memchr` may always look at `maxlen` bytes no matter the contents of those bytes. Does the contract of `strnlen` only allow it to look at all `maxlen` bytes if there is no NUL terminator? If so, the size in memory of `str` may be less than `maxlen` bytes, in which case `memchr` might try to read invalid memory locations. Is this correct?

Comment: With care, yes!  I don’t think `memchr()` will read beyond the first occurrence of the sought character.

Comment: *"...in which case memchr might try to read invalid memory locations. Is this correct?"* -- if that happens, you would have invoked UB with `strlen` as well as there is no `'\0'`. So it is somewhat a *circular-hypothetical*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the implementation posted is conforming: `memchr()` is not supposed to read bytes from `str` beyond the first occurrence of `'\0'`.

> **C17 7.24.5.1 The `memchr` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
> void *memchr(const void *s, int c, size_t n);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The `memchr` function locates the first occurrence of `c` (converted to an `unsigned char`) in the initial `n` characters (each interpreted as `unsigned char`) of the object pointed to by `s`. The implementation shall behave as if it reads the characters sequentially and stops as soon as a matching character is found.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The `memchr` function returns a pointer to the located character, or a null pointer if the character does not occur in the object.

`memchr` may be implemented with efficient techniques that test multiple bytes at a time, potentially reading beyond the first matching byte, but only if this does not cause any visible side effects.

Answer (score 2):

> I assume that `memchr` may always look at `maxlen` bytes no matter the contents of those bytes.

That assumption is wrong. [From POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memchr.html):

> Implementations shall behave as if they read the memory byte by byte from the beginning of the bytes pointed to by *s* and stop at the first occurrence of *c* (if it is found in the initial *n* bytes).

Comment: Perhaps update to answer the question originally presented.